Can I copyright the recording of someone reading a work licensed under the terms of the Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License?
A written work is published under the terms of the Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License. This is explicitly stated by the publisher:

Open Access This book is licensed under the terms of the Creative
Commons Attribution
4.0 International License (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/), which permits use,
sharing, adaptation, distribution and reproduction in any medium or
format, as long as you give appropriate credit to the original
author(s) and the source, provide a link to the Creative Commons
license and indicate if changes were made.

If I were to record someone reading this book, would it violate the terms of the license to claim copyright to the recording but not to the content?

This might be better suited to Open Source SE. In fact, I bet it's already been asked there.

"Open Source Stack Exchange is a question & answer site for people producing, distributing, marketing and monetizing Free and Open projects." - This line dissuaded me from posting my question there as I am effectively asking if a performance of something open can be, er, something other than open, but I didn't post to their Meta to get clarification. Perhaps I could have worded the question differently to be from the perspective of the CC-BY rights holder. Hm.

That's fair enough. I spend a lot of time there so I know that there are a lot of experts on the CC licenses there who may not post here. I don't actually know if it's strictly OT there (and it's clearly fine here). I didn't find an existing question that was exactly the same as yours, though.

I spent some time searching all of SE and couldn't find a question that seemed the same as mine on any of the sites.

Does this Q need a jurisdiction tag?

So you're conveyed a copyrighted work under CC-BY, and you want to make a recording of a performance of that work. You want to know your legal rights. I claim you have almost exactly the same rights (over your recording!) as you would have if the original copyrighted work were created by you.
First, let's get some easy things out of the way. Performance of the work (reading it aloud) is one of the rights reserved for the copyright holder. You are correct that CC-BY permits you to perform the work, as long as the author is attributed. Likewise you are allowed to record that performance. Since that recording fixes the performance into a physical medium, we can ask about the copyright in the work (if any).
Your rights depend on whether the work is considered a derivative work (it probably is). This means that it has sufficient originality to merit copyright protection in its own right. For example, if the "reading" was done by a text-to-speech generator, then there is probably no copyright in the recording. But if a person reads the work aloud, this probably does merit protection. Again, CC-BY allows you to make derivative works.
As soon as you are sure the work is a derivative, you have two copyrights to consider. The copyright in the book (B) and the copyright in the recording (R). Your right to produce R at all is dictated by the license terms of B. If you violate the license terms, you can no longer create or distribute copies of R. So what are the license terms? CC are very clear:


Attribution — You must give appropriate credit, provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made . You may do so in any
reasonable manner, but not in any way that suggests the licensor
endorses you or your use.
No additional restrictions — You may not apply legal terms or technological measures that legally restrict others from doing
anything the license permits.


So you must prominently attribute the author of B whenever you distribute R. And you may not apply any technological measures (like DRM) to prevent people from adapting or remixing B. This probably implies that you cannot apply DRM to your own work, because (for example) I should be able to transcribe it automatically to obtain a copy of B. But this is just my guess, and I don't think it has ever been legally tested. I would recommend not applying DRM to the recording at all.
That's it. You still have your copyright in the recording. The question you're asking is what right do other people have, if you distribute a copy of R to them. This depends on the license under which you convey R. You can convey it under any terms you like, provided they do not violate the terms of B. By default, this means that the receiver may not modify the work, they may not distribute exact copies, and they may not make derivative works of your recording.
If they do so anyway, then you can sue them for copyright infringement of your recording. This is not prohibited by the CC-BY license.
Hypothetical: what about "copyleft" licenses?
The situation would be different if the original work was conveyed under a "copyleft" license, like CC-BY-SA. The "share-alike" provision of that license adds an additional term to the license of B, saying that if you prepare derivative works, and you distribute those derivative works to a third party, then the derived work must be conveyed under the same terms as the original work.
In that case, if you were to attempt to distribute your recording under restrictive terms, then doing so would violate the terms of the original work, and you would be infringing on their copyright. That's the "viral" effect people often talk about regarding licenses like CC-BY-SA. But this is an additional restriction relative to CC-BY: since CC-BY contains no such stipulation, you may distribute derived works under restrictive terms. People call often call such licenses "permissive", since they permit additional restrictions to be made on downstream remixers.

I think that your use of the phrase "almost exactly" is severely overstated.  If the OP has created an audio recording as a completely independent work, their copyright would cover, for example, the "lyrics" (or transcript or whatever the relevant term is for the type of work).  As you've put it, it seems that the only copyright that the OP has is over the exact recording.  They can't prevent others from reproducing the lyrics, or from creating their own recordings, and, not only that, but they have to point everyone to the original lyrics in their recording.  This is pretty weak, IMHO.

@Him No, it isn't. That line refers to OP's rights over their work (which is what they asked about). Of course I don't mean to imply they have rights over the work they didn't create. The OP has not created a completely independent work: they have created a derived work. The only copyright the OP does have is in their recording. The fact the OP didn't do much work (and thus doesn't have very useful rights) is incidental to the question of what their rights are. I thought I was very clear about that.

"I claim you have almost exactly the same rights (over your recording!) as you would have if the original copyrighted work were created by you."  -- so, if you don't mean to say that they have almost exactly the same rights as if they had created the written work, what is "the original copyrighted work" you refer to here?  If you mean "the recording", then the rights aren't almost exact, they are exact:  it is true that the copyrights they have over the recording are the copyrights they have over the recording, but this statement isn't very informative.

@Him The "original copyrighted work" is the book. The rights are not exactly the same: OP may not distribute their recording with DRM, and they may not distribute their recording without attributing the book's author. This is very far from obvious - see for example the other answer to this question which confuses the obligations of CC-BY with those of CC-BY-SA. I am starting to wonder whether you read beyond the first paragraph.

Ignore that last sentence, it's more rude than I needed to be (and I can't edit the comment)

It might be a good idea to point out that, in the case of CC-BY-SA, you must assert copyright in the recording because doing so is necessary to meet your obligation to make it available under the CC-BY-SA license.

I don't think that you can.
This Creative Commons license does not surrender the copyright, it grants others a license to "use" and "adapt" the copyrighted work (as relevant to this question).
A performance of a work by reading it aloud is part of the bundle of rights that a copyright holder owns, which would be infringing, but for the license. The license, however, allows for "use" and "adaptation" in a way that seems to include use and adaptation through performance of the work by reading it.
A license gives permission to do something specific that would otherwise be infringement, but it doesn't surrender any part of the underlying bundle of rights included in the copyright including the performance right.
So, I don't think that someone could copyright the performance apart from the content that was read.

I think you are right about performances, but OP asks about a recording of the performance. Wouldn't that be a derivative work, with its own copyright?

@preferred_anon Fair point. Same bottom line conclusion.

isn't it literally the opposite? They specifically ask about "claiming copyright in the recording but not in the content".

Performing without a license is infringement. Creating a derivative work without a license is infringement. Both acts infringe one of the rights arising from the original copyright. So, either way, it is infringing.

Now I am very confused. They do have a license to do those things! There's no question at all that OP is infringing anyone's copyright - what do you mean exactly? And how does it relate to your conclusion "I don't think someone could copyright the performance"?

I think this analysis of the specifics of CC-BY's provisions is wrong.  They grant license to "share" the original work, explicitly defining that to include public performance, and more broadly to include similar protected activities.  They also license the creation of derived works that modify the original in ways that require permission to perform. See sections 2.a.1, 2.a.4, 1.a, 1.c, 1.g, 1.i. And certainly the intent of the license, as widely publicized by its author, is to be broadly permissive.

You already own the copyright, but …
By making the recording, you have created a derivative work - an audiobook of the written book. The licence allows you to do this - it’s an adaptation. You (and the performer) own that copyright.
However, you must release the work under CCA 4.0 and attribute the original author. So you own the copyright but there is little opportunity for profit. You can sell copies of your recording but if someone copies them using CCA 4.0 and undercuts you, there’s nothing you can do. You can, however, sue for any use outside CCA 4.0, for example, if they use it without attribution.

I don't understand "However, you must release the work under CCA". The original work remains under CC-BY (I think this is the usual abbreviation), but the derivative is ARR unless conveyed under another license. A person who obtains the recording could not, for example, play it out loud, or set it to music, or exercise any of the other rights that the OP holds by making the recording. The OP cannot stop someone from making their own recording of the CC-BY work. I would agree with you if the OP said "CC-BY-SA" (the share-alike license). What do you think?

Note: the derivative work must attribute the original author, that is also true. I think the OP also may not put any effective technological measures preventing copying of the work (DRM). But the OP retains their copyright in the derivative.

Slight pedantry - "you must release the work under CCA 4.0" implies that keeping it to oneself is not an option.  But it's perfectly reasonable (and very common) to create a derived work without publishing it, and that's certainly not a breach of the licence.  All of the second paragraph is conditional on "if you distribute the adapted work..."
